# Intellisense for Ruby, Ruby on Rails, Python

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, autocomplete, ide

Are there any intellisense options for languages like Ruby, Ruby on Rails, Python, etc?

This could include an IDE, if necessary. I'm looking for something like Visual Studio's c# or Eclipse's java intellisense.

Comment: Try http://www.jetbrains.com - they have IDE's for Ruby, Python and others

Comment: I'd be especially interested in _free_ ones. Aptana is usually my go-to for Ruby / Rails (although I haven't used it for a while), but IIRC its autocomplete has some problems with the dynamic nature of members and types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure are!!

jetbrains has full line of ide's.

PyCharm and RubyMine

http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/

Answer (score 3):

Because of the dynamic nature of these languages, implementing things like auto-completion is quite difficult, and only works for some cases.

Examples for Python: [pydev](http://pydev.org/) (eclipse plug-in), [rope](http://rope.sourceforge.net/) (this is a refactoring library that can easily be used into emacs),[anyting with ipython](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PythonProgrammingInEmacs#toc13) (again, an emacs mode).

Anyways, don't expect them to be as powerful as the tools you have for Java or C#.

Rope for example, does a bit of type inference to figure out parameter types in order to give you completion suggestions. This might take an awfully long amount of time for big codebases, thus making the feature useless on such codebases.

[anyting with ipython](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PythonProgrammingInEmacs#toc13) on the other hand actually spawns a background python process that imports your current module and any modules it references, and does runtime checking on entities (classes, functions, global variables...) in those modules. Because it doesn't do type inference, it can't give you any auto-completion suggestions for variables passed as parameters or local variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use vim with [dot files](http://skwp.github.io/dotfiles/) which includes syntax highlight, smart indentation, auto-complete for Ruby among other features. Although it had been worked for MacOS, but you can easily adapt to your OS if you're using other.

Another option includes [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) for Eclipse or Jetbrains [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/). So try all the solutions and decide what best fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

My [vim setup](https://github.com/srathbun/vim-plugins) uses the supertabcomplete, snipmate, and python-mode plugins for mostly intellisense completion.

It's windows centric, because that is what I develop on, but just change the paths in the vimrc file after cloning and you should be up and functional.

Answer (score 0):

[Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) also supports this to a limited extent. Auto-completion is very difficult for dynamic languages, so this will display recently use variables/methods, and anything else that is nearby that matches the fuzzy text filter.